# different distances between bars using plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I created a bar chart using plotly in rshiny. For some reason, there is a much wider space in between the 5th and the 6th bars. Wonder what caused this issue? 
Below is the output of this chart browsed in webpage.
[image]
Below is the sample code for your reference.

```
# # Output - index option bar chart
  output$index_opt_bar <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(index_opt_bar_data(), x = 'SPX 1yCap', y = ~SPX_Annual_Cap_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 1yCap',
            text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Annual_Cap_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
            marker = list(color = 'rgb(128,171,205)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'SPX 2yCap', y = ~SPX_Biannual_Cap_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 2yCap',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Biannual_Cap_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(252,168,128)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'SPX 1yBinary', y = ~SPX_Declared_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 1yBinary',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Declared_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(160,113,160)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'SPX 1yPar', y = ~SPX_Annual_Par_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 1yPar',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Annual_Par_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(246,203,105)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'SPX 1yEnPar', y = ~SPX_Annual_EnPar_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 1yEnPar',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Annual_EnPar_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(214,134,152)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'SPX 2yPar|2yEnPar|5yEnPar', y = ~SPX_Other_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'SPX 2yPar|2yEnPar|5yEnPar',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*SPX_Other_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(255,222,220)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'EAFE & ACWI', y = ~INTL_All_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'EAFE & ACWI',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*INTL_All_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(147,147,155)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      add_trace( x = 'BEI', y = ~BEI_All_FV, type = 'bar', name = 'BEI',
                 text = ~paste(as.integer(100*BEI_All_FV/Total_FV),'%'), textposition = 'outside', textfont = list(color = '#000000'),
                 marker = list(color = 'rgb(151,232,212)',line = list(color = '#000000', width = 1))) %>%
      layout(title = "<b>Inforce Distribution<b>", titlefont = list(color = '#000000'), 
             paper_bgcolor = '#ffffff', plot_bgcolor = '#ffffff',
             xaxis = list(title = "", showticklabels = FALSE, 
                          categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = c('SPX 1yCap','SPX 2yCap','SPX 1yBinary','SPX 1yPar','SPX 1yEnPar','SPX 2yCap|2yEnPar|5yEnPar',"EAFE & ACWI", "BEI")),
             yaxis = list(title = "", color = '#000000',
                          showgrid = TRUE, gridcolor = '#000000'),
             legend = list(x = 0, y = -80, font = list(size = 10, color = '#000000'), orientation = 'h', traceorder = "normal"))
  })
```

Much thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a data sample?

Comment: The answer below solves my problem! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Cool! If the suggestion solves your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. By now you've gathered more than 20 reputation points and earned the right to award posts with your up-votes. Using your vote will also award you badges over time. Try it out! Maybe your question will attract a few votes of itself ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that your `categoryarray` in your `layout` does not exactly match your data. In particular, you have `SPX 2yCap|2yEnPar|5yEnPar` in the `categoryarray` for your `xaxis` but your corresponding `add_trace` has `SPX 2yPar|2yEnPar|5yEnPar`. With the longer variable name it may have been hard to catch the difference there.

You may have noticed that your legend matches the order of bars, except for this variable. The variable `SPX 2yPar|2yEnPar|5yEnPar` is at the end, and an empty space for the mislabeled variable. If a category plotted is not specified in the array, it will be found at the end of the categories in `categoryarray`.

According to the Plotly [reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-categoryorder):

> If a category is not found in the `categoryarray` array, the sorting
>   behavior for that attribute will be identical to the "trace" mode. The
>   unspecified categories will follow the categories in `categoryarray`.

To illustrate, consider the example below:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  count = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
  names = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth")
)

p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~names, y = ~count, type = "bar")
p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(categoryarray = c("First", "Second", "Somethingelse", "Fourth"), categoryorder = "array"))
p
```

[image: plot with categories out of order]